# Recode observation in column depending on different column

Tags: r, data-cleaning, recode

I have a dataset called 'survey' with rows of individual ID's, and columns with many questions. I need to recode the value in 1 column as `NA` and move the observation to the other column.

For example:

```
ID    Food    Vegetable 
aaa   NA       NA 
bbb   NA       lemon
ccc   NA       sprout
ddd   fruit    NA
eee   fruit    NA
fff   NA       watermelon
```

I want to change the `lemon` and `watermelon` observations, belonging to ID `bbb` and `fff` to put them into the `Food` column and rename them `fruit` (survey respondents put them in the wrong column) and leave `NA` behind in the `vegetable` column.

To look like:

```
   ID    Food        Vegetable 
    aaa   NA         NA 
    bbb   fruit      NA
    ccc   NA         sprout
    ddd   fruit      NA
    eee   fruit      NA
    fff   fruit      NA
```

I've used:

```
survey<- survey %>%
    mutate(food = if_else(str_detect(Vegetable,"(lemon)|(watermelon)"),"fruit", Food))
```

Which works to convert `NA` to `fruit` in the `food` column, but it doesn't concert to `NA` in the `vegetable` column, it also turns all the other fruits in the `food` column to `NA`!

DATA:

```
    structure(list(ID = c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff"
), Food = c(NA, NA, NA, "fruit", "fruit", NA), Vegetable = c(NA, 
"lemon", "sprout", NA, NA, "watermelon")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

P.S.: This is a follow up to [a previous question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62518774/recode-observation-in-column-for-a-specific-id) which was answered. This isn't exactly the same question as before, which is why I started a new one.

dplyr version (1.0.2)

Comment: After the step, you can do `mutate(Vegetable = NA_character_)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to update `Food` and `Vegetable` based on whether `Vegetable` values are `%in%` a given list, `not_vegetables`:

```r
not_vegetables <- c("grape", "tomato")

df %>%
  mutate(Food = if_else(Vegetable %in% not_vegetables, "fruit", Food),
         Vegetable = if_else(Vegetable %in% not_vegetables, NA_character_, Vegetable))
```

Another way is to `replace`, `across` both columns, and do the `if_else` inside:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(across(
    c(Food, Vegetable), 
    ~replace(., 
             Vegetable %in% not_vegetables, 
             if_else(cur_column() == "Food", 'fruit', NA_character_))
    ))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these seem to have worked? The first solution ran, but no change to data. the second solution gave an error: ```Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x Formula shorthand must be wrapped in `where()`.

  # Bad
  data %>% select(~...)

  # Good
  data %>% select(where(~...))
ℹ Input `..1` is `across(...)`.
Backtrace:
>```

Comment: I tested both locally before posting, sounds like a version issue, and/or something about how your real data is set up. What version of dplyr do you have? `across` was introduced in April. Can you edit your post to include `dput` of your data, or of your toy df? That will make it easier to know what's going on.

Comment: Weirdly, when I do this in a new R file, it works...is it possible `%in% ` is masked by another package?

Comment: Glad it worked.  Re masking, maybe?  You can look at `conflicts(detail=TRUE)` to see which functions have conflicts in your environment.  Note that `%in%` is a base R function, I don't think anything in tidyverse overwrites it.

Answer (score 1):

Using base R could you try this:

```
#Conditional
values <- c('grape','tomato')
df$Food <- ifelse(df$Vegetable %in% values,'fruit',df$Food)
df$Vegetable <- ifelse(df$Vegetable %in% values,NA,df$Vegetable)
```

Output:

```
df
   ID  Food Vegetable
1 aaa fruit      <NA>
2 bbb fruit      <NA>
3 ccc fruit      <NA>
4 ddd fruit      <NA>
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"), Food = c(NA, 
NA, "fruit", "fruit"), Vegetable = c("grape", "tomato", NA, NA
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```